# How to find and remove invalid geometry in a multilinestring python geodataframe?

Tags: python, geopandas, shapely, linestring, well-known-binary

I have original data as a 700000's rows excel, with geometry data in hexwkb format.
I want to plot it and make some spatial operations on it like intersect, distance and buffer, on a jupyter notebook.
Half of the geometries are null. Part of the remaining ones have apparently invalid geometries.

I had succeed in plotting the first 100 lines, apparently with fine geometries, but I'm struggling to plot all the data.

This code worked for lines with no geometry problems:

**Data example**

id (int64) | geom (object)

1 | '0105000020E610000001000...

```
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely import wkb
from shapely.geometry import MultiLineString


df=pd.read_excel(r'trips.xlsx')
trips= df.dropna(subset=['geom'])


# create column with converted geometry

def convert_to_hexwkb(geomString):
    geometry = wkb.loads(geomString, hex=True)
    return geometry
trips['geometry']=trips['geom'].map(convert_to_hexwkb)
trips.drop('geom', axis=1, inplace=True)


# convert to GeoDataFrame

gtrips=gpd.GeoDataFrame(trips)

print(gtrips['geometry'][0])
>> MULTILINESTRING ((-9.1474504470825 38.744022369385, -9.147529602050801 38.744121551514, -9.14...


# show trips map

gtrips.plot()
>> got a nice map here
```

But when I run this to the entire data I get the following error given from the shapely -> geos library, during conversion of string to hexwkb:

> *WKBReadingError: Could not create geometry because of errors while reading input.*
>
> *IllegalArgumentException: point array must contain 0 or >1 elements*

I couldn't find how to apply Geopandas.GeoSeries`.is_empty` function to find empty geometries, because it was not a geodataframe at that point.
Same for `is_valid` function from shapely library, since the field was not geometry type.

I've tried to delete exceptional rows with this:

```
for i, item in enumerate(trips['geom']):
   try:
    trips.at[i,'geometry'] = wkb.loads(item, hex=True)
      #wkb.loads(item,hex=True)
   except:
    trips.drop([i], inplace=True)
```

And got the errors:

> *IllegalArgumentException: point array must contain 0 or >1 elements*
>
> *WKBReadingError: Could not create geometry because of errors while reading input.*
>
> *another exception occurred: KeyError: '[791] not found in axis'* - This related with how the for cycle  was constructed probably.

If I run this for debug:

```
def convert_to_hexwkb(geomString):
    try:
        geometry = wkb.loads(geomString, hex=True)
        return geometry
    except:
        return np.nan

trips['geometry']=trips['geom'].map(convert_to_hexwkb)
```

I get these errors, multiplied for several lines:

> *ParseException: Unexpected EOF parsing WKB*
>
> *ParseException: Premature end of HEX string*

Any clue of what should I do to clean geometries of my dataset?

Comment: At least you can filter out trips which have exactly one point.

Comment: What do you get when using `trips = df.dropna(subset=['geom']).reset_index(drop=True)` and then `for` loop?

Comment: @KadirŞahbaz, made no difference, I've got the same errors.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
import shapely
excel = r"C:\TEMP\ovrig_vag.xlsx" #Roads as multilinestrings wkb's, and various attributes
df = pd.read_excel(excel) #Create a pandas df
# df.shape
# Out: (474399, 11)

#I have a column named wkb. Modify some rows to make them invalid:
dfempty = df.sample(100)
dfempty["wkb"] = '' #Empty strings
df.update(dfempty)

dfnone = df.sample(100)
dfnone["wkb"] = None #None
df.update(dfnone)

dfabc = df.sample(100)
dfabc["wkb"] = 'abc' #Invalid string
df.update(dfabc)

def trywkb(wkb):
    """A function which tries to create a shapely geometry from a wkb,
        if the geometry is valid, it returns it and the string 'valid',
        if not returns the input wkb and the exception message"""
    try:
        geometry = shapely.from_wkb(wkb)
        return pd.Series([geometry, "valid"])
    except Exception as e:
        return pd.Series([wkb, str(e)])

df[["geometry", "validity"]] = df.apply(lambda x: trywkb(x.wkb), axis=1)
# df[["geometry", "validity"]].head(3)
# Out: 
#                                             geometry validity
# 0  MULTILINESTRING ((395958.5480000004 6133594.20...    valid
# 1  MULTILINESTRING ((396293.9639999997 6133965.64...    valid
# 2  MULTILINESTRING ((396325.72300000023 6133982.2...    valid

#There are valid geometries, and two types of invalid geometries:
# df.validity.unique()
# array(['valid', 'ParseException: Unexpected EOF parsing WKB',
#        'ParseException: Premature end of HEX string'], dtype=object)

#Create a geodataframe of the valid
dfvalid = df.loc[df["validity"]=="valid"]
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(data=dfvalid, geometry=dfvalid["geometry"])
```